# Why CSS is not working on my GitHub pages

Tags: html, css

https://github.com/Leevance-singh/tech

CSS is not working on my GitHub pages and I've searched more than 40 forums and solutions but still can't get it working. My `href` is correctly pointed towards **CSS file** but still can't see changes live on website.

Comment: Your css file has the extension in uppercase (`.CSS` instead of `.css`), while you include it with lower case. On some systems that's two different files. You should rename it.

Comment: Note that only changing the case on some systems make git not understand it. So you should rename the file to something completely different, then commit commit, rename to the correct name, commit

Comment: Please include all relevant HTML and CSS as well as folder structure in the question itself. The link to your GitHub repo will not help future readers with the same question when it is changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone. Now i can use css on my website. Error was because of case sensitive file names.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you store your CSS file in a separate folder name it as css and then name your file as styles.css with no uppercase letters.

Change your link as `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">`

See linking approach here https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/553bcfc6d3292f7e1b000760